# Analytical expression of mutual information between a multivariate Gaussian and a binary class variable

Tags: conditional-probability, entropy, mutual-information, conditional-entropy

The goal is to construct settings that allow analytical computations of the mutual information in the form:

```
$$I(X; Y) = H(X) - H(X | Y)$$
```

I am wondering if that is possible when X is some multivariate Gaussian and Y is a binary class variable.

Here is an attempt at showing if that is possible. Is the following statement correct?

Let $Y$ be a binary random variable with $y_i \in [0, 1]$ be realizations of $Y$. Let $X$ be a random vector with $x_i \in \mathbb{R}^d$ be a realization of $X$.

One can set $x_i$ to be either sampled from $U_1 \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_1, \Sigma_1)$, or $U_2 \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_2, \Sigma_2)$. Then $\mathbf{X} = [x_1, x_2, ..., x_{n/2}, ..., x_n]^T$, where $u_1 = \{x_i\}_{1}^{n/2} \sim U_1$ and $u_2 = \{x_i\}_{n/2+1}^n \sim U_2$.

Next, construct $\mathbf{Y} = [y_1, y_2, ..., y_{n/2}, ..., y_n]^T$, where $y_i = 0$ for $i \in [1, n/2]$ and $y_i = 1$ for $i \in [n/2 + 1, n]$.

### Conditional Entropy H(X | Y) Attempt

conditional entropy of $H(X | Y)$ is simply the entropy of the individual multivariate-Gaussians. I.e. $H(X | Y) = H(X | Y=1) + H(X |Y=0)$

### Entropy H(X) Attempt

The entropy of $H(X)$ is

$$H(X) = -\sum_{x \in X} p(x) log p(x) = -(\sum_{x \in U_1} p(x) log p(x) + \sum_{x \in U_2} p(x) log p(x)) = H(U_1) + H(U_2)$$

However, then the equations seem to cancel out suggesting $I(X;Y) = 0$, which intuitively doesn't make sense to me.